# Object gets unwanted width and height

Tags: pages

Is it possible to stop WordPress adding a width and height to an object when you pate it in to the source view?

When I paste in

```
<a href="#"><object data="grid-linked-in.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></a>
```

WP changes it to

```
<a href="#"><object width="300" height="150" type="image/svg+xml" data="grid-linked-in.svg"></object></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
add_filter( 'media_send_to_editor', 'remove_width_height_attribute', 10 );

function remove_width_height_attribute( $html ) {
   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
   return $html;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the width and height attributes? Also keep in mind that you _can_ set `%` values that are calculated from the rendered parent/container element. Also you might want to _prepend_ the white space and not append it, as there's a 100% chance that there's at least one white space in front, but not necessary one appended. And your `\d*` should probably be [`\d*[,|\.]?\d+`](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fGx) as there could be float values. Hint: Try the `\DomDocument` class instead.

Comment: I am using svg images around the site and I want to make them interactive. It is a responsive site and having Wordpress set the sizes prevents me using the images at full size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this:

```
$('object').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('width height');
});
```

That should remove those attributes for you. You can even set attributes as well if need be. Put the following inside the function above (Obviously you can change the attributes as need be).

```
$(this).css('max-height',500);
```